# Why do I get 'File only saved locally, not to server' with Eclipse Force.com IDE?

Tags: force.com, ide, eclipse

I have installed Force.com IDE (see versions of all components below).  If I try to do something simple like increase the length a custom text field, I get

> File only saved locally, not to server

and

> Save error: Conflict found while preparing to save 'Account.object' to server.  Remote instance has been updated since last save or sync.  Use the Synchronize Perspective to resolve the conflict.    Account.object    /MA Dev/src/objects    line 1    Force.com save problem

I refreshed from server and then got this 8 times:

> Refresh error: Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type:ConnectedApp and file name:Salesforce_Chatterbox.    package.xml    /MA Dev/Referenced Packages/Salesforce1 and Chatter Apps    line 1    Force.com retrieve problem

Environment is

> Spring '16 Dev Org with custom domain
>
> Spring '16 Force.com IDE (36.0.0)
>
> Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2)
>
> Java 8 Update 74
>
> Windows 7 64 bit

I have reviewed other threads, I needed to click 'work online' as default was offline, still having above issues.

I can sync the object with server and the changes are propogated but this has to be done every time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a project that you've had on your machine for a while? Did it go through an upgrade from a v34 or v35 project? Do you have other Force.com projects in eclipse that are working properly? In cases such as this, I would first try to create a new Force.com Project and see if that new project also exhibits the same behavior or works properly.

Comment: Shortest path can be to create a new project

Comment: Maybe because your force.com IDE is configured to work offline?